# Iterate through dataframe and create new column based if values in columns are not NaN (Pandas)

Tags: python, pandas

```py
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'subsegment': ['corp', np.nan, 'terr'],
    'region': ['japan', np.nan, np.nan],
    'subregion': [np.nan, 'se', 'ne'], 
    'segment': [np.nan,'ent','comm']
})
```

I am trying to iterate through the above dataframe and if the value is not NaN than adding the column header as the value or part of the value (depending on how many NaNs) in the new column "Mode".

Original DF

| subsegment | region | subregion | segment |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| corp | japan | NaN | NaN |
| NaN | NaN | se | ent |
| terr | NaN | ne | comm |

Desired Output DF

| subsegment | region | subregion | segment | mode |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| corp | japan | NaN | NaN | subsegment-region |
| NaN | NaN | se | ent | subregion-segment |
| terr | NaN | ne | comm | subsegment-subregion-segment |

I have tried to create separate smaller dfs with all the combinations of the columns to which are not null and then concatenating those dfs together but this seems extremely inefficient.

```
df1 = df.loc[~(df['subsegment'].isna()) & (~df['region'].isna()) & (~df['region'].isna())]
df2 = df.loc[~(df['region'].isna()) & (~df['subregion'].isna()) & (~df['segment'].isna())]
df3 = df.loc[~(df['subsegment'].isna()) & (~df['subregion'].isna()) & (~df['segment'].isna())] 

pd.concat(df1,df2,df3.....)
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use a [`dot`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.dot.html) product:

```
df['mode'] = (df.notna() @ (df.columns+'-')).str[:-1]
```

Output:

```
  subsegment region subregion segment                          mode
0       corp  japan       NaN     NaN             subsegment-region
1        NaN    NaN        se     ent             subregion-segment
2       terr    NaN        ne    comm  subsegment-subregion-segment
```

Alternatively, with a classical [`groupby.agg`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.agg.html):

```
s = df.notna().stack()

df['mode'] = s[s].reset_index().groupby('level_0')['level_1'].agg('-'.join)
```

Or a custom aggregation:

```
df['mode'] = df.notna().mul(df.columns).agg(lambda x: '-'.join(x[x.ne('')]), axis=1)
```

Comment: The only thing I'd say to this is that it might be a bit too clever, so I think it might need backing up with a comment if you put it in actual code. But I like it.

Comment: @roganjosh I added a more classical approach, the dot product is however quite fast ;)

Answer (score 2):

You can use the below code. I'm using `apply` with a custom function that just finds the columns that are not null

```
from itertools import compress
def temp_func(x, cols):

    list_a = (~x.isna()).to_list()
    ret = list(compress(cols, list_a))
    return '-'.join(ret)
df['mode']= df.apply(lambda x: temp_func(x, list(df.columns)), axis=1)
print(df)
```

Ouput:

```
  subsegment region subregion segment                          mode
0       corp  japan       NaN     NaN             subsegment-region
1        NaN    NaN        se     ent             subregion-segment
2       terr    NaN        ne    comm  subsegment-subregion-segment
```

Answer (score 2):

A possible solution:

```
a = df.columns.values * (~pd.isnull(df.values))

df['mode'] = ['-'.join(a[i,:][a[i,:] != '']) for i in range(a.shape[0])]
```

---

Alternatively:

```
df['mode'] = df.apply(lambda x: '-'.join(df.columns[~x.isna()]), axis=1)
```

---

Output:

```
  subsegment region subregion segment                          mode
0       corp  japan       NaN     NaN             subsegment-region
1        NaN    NaN        se     ent             subregion-segment
2       terr    NaN        ne    comm  subsegment-subregion-segment
```